# Assign empty string to a variable and change the value while executing the powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have a sample powershell script say test.ps1 with the below contents

```
$Arg=" "

Function EnableArg()
{
    $Arg= "arg"
}

Function DisableArg()
{
    $Arg=  " "
}

Function Print()
{
    Write-Host "Value - $Arg"
}
```

If I run this script using powershell ISE and try the following:

1. Print - > Value -
2. EnableArg
3. Print -> Value -

When I executed step 2 and then step 3, I was expecting

> Value - arg

But unfortunately it shows

> Value -

Not sure if the script is being reset everytime. I also tried explicitly declaring the type to [string] but no luck. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You never set `$backupArg` to anything.

Comment: You need to read [`about_Scopes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes)

Comment: @DougMaurer sorry, edited the question

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks! that solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of crossing scope boundaries, I recommend you use functions in a more appropriate fashion. You pass in parameters/arguments and you return output. Meaning you will capture the output of a function in a variable and pass arguments into a function.

```
Function EnableArg()
{
    "arg"
}

Function DisableArg()
{
    " "
}

Function Print($InternalArg)
{
    Write-Host "Value - $InternalArg"
}

$arg = EnableArg

print $arg

$arg = DisableArg

Print $arg
```

Comment: @sandeep-bhat Or use keyword 'return' for clarity